# SameSite cookies problem with google chrome update

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome, cookies, samesite

my app built when angular and expressJs was working fine until i had some problems with cookies.

i have warning message:

> A cookie associated with a resource at http://127.0.0.1/ was set with
> `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will
> only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked
> `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under
> Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

To set a cookie to secure it must be with https but i am only in development so i have to use localhost.
When set SameSite=None and secure=false, i have an error when i try te GET data from the back end:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

I disabled SameSite by default cookies, Enable removing SameSite=None cookies and Cookies without SameSite must be secure from chrome://flags/ but still not working.

So how can i, fix this behavior in development mode ? thank you

Comment: Do you have any adblock/other extension? I don't think that's problem with SameSite cookie flag. (if so, it will only block cookie, not request)

Comment: Yes i desabled adblock and it's working now! I forgot that my url contains /ads. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an adblocker or other extension that is blocking the request.

I don't think that's problem with SameSite cookie flag. (if so, it will only block the cookie, not the request)